# Pass String Parameters to WP REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I can pass integer values to WP REST API. But, cannot pass non-numeric characters. It gives error.

This is what I used...

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'crowdapi/v1', '/register/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<username>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'userCheck',
    ) );
} );
```

Any idea how to pass strings as well.. ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found it myself...

use `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` instead of `\d` for strings

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'crowdapi/v1', '/register/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<number>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'userCheck',
    ) );
} );
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me: `/(?P<slug>\w+)`

Answer (score 3):

Try below code for define endpoint as well..

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'crowdapi/v1', '/register/(?P<id>\d)/(?P<username>\d)', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'userCheck',
    ) );
} );
```

Comment: I've used `(?P<stringvar>.+)` as well as `(?P<stringvar>[^/]+)` for string params. It really depends on what you need to get back as well as put-in.

Answer (score 0):

you need to try this, it will work

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'crowdapi/v1', '/register/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<username>\w+)', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'userCheck',
    ) );
} );
```